# Handle null pointer exception when calling methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I have a case when I call a method in many services.

```
    private AmazonS3 getS3Amazon(String access, String secret){
        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = null;
        try {

            amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http...", "us-west-1"))
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(access, secret)))
                    .build();
            Assert.isTrue(amazonS3 != null, "amazonS3 is null");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return amazonS3;
    }
```

In this method, I'm checking for null in  `Assert.isTrue(amazonS3 != null, "amazonS3 is null");`

Now in other methods when I have to call `getS3Amazon`

```
public JsonObject createS3Something( Map<String, String>params) {
        //code

       AmazonS3 amazonS3 = this.getS3Amazon(params.get("access"), params.get("secret"));

       //other code using amazonS3
       amazonS3.doSomething();

       return response;
}
```

Why I  get a warning that 'A “NullPointerException” could be thrown'?

I know that I can check `amazonS3 != null` in `createS3Something` but while I'm checking for null on getS3Amazon is that necessary? What's the best approach in this case?

Comment: Don't use `Assert` in your production code. Even if you were to use `Assert`, you should use [`Assert.assertNotNull(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertNotNull(java.lang.Object)) for not `null`. But there are other possibilities (e.g. [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html)) to check for `null`. This is also understood by most static analyzers and the warning should go awaay.

Comment: A NullPointerException could be thrown because if an exception is thrown when trying to create amazonS3, you just print it, then return null. Don't catch the exception. All you're doing by catching it is hide it and cause harder to diagnose NPEs later.

Comment: @Turing85 if I use Optional, I still have to check if `amazonS3` is present in all other methods where I call `getS3Amazon`, which means I have to do the same check-in several methods, is there any way to do this check on the `getS3Amazon` method?

Comment: You don't actually call `getS3Amazon` in your second code snippet. Is this a typo?

Comment: @arcadeblast77 yes a typo, I updated it

Answer (score 0):

This statement `Assert.isTrue(amazonS3 != null, "amazonS3 is null");` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when `amazons3` is null i.e. is when the `boolean` expression evaluates to `false`, in your case when `amazonS3` is `null`.

The exception will be caught and handled in the subsequent `catch` block and `amazonS3` object will still point to `null`.

Now that the exception was handled the return statement will return the `null` value to the caller.

So that is why you get that warning.

You can slightly tweak your code to use `Optional<AmazonS3>`:

```
 private Optional<AmazonS3> getS3Amazon(String access, String secret){
        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = null;
        try {    
            amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http...", "us-west-1"))
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(access, secret)))
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(amazonS3);
    }
```

In the client code just check if the value is null/non-null and take action using `Optional.ifPresent()`:

```
public JsonObject createS3Something( Map<String, String>params) {
        //code
       Optional<AmazonS3> amazonS3 = this.getS3Amazon(params.get("access"), params.get("secret"));

       //other code using amazonS3
       amazonS3.ifPresent(s3 -> s3.doSomething());

       return response;
}
```

Comment: Yes,  what is the best way in these cases to check for null values without repeating the same code in all methods?

Comment: @kfxoy50h.ajq whenever there is a slightest possibility of  a object being `null` we should wrap that  object  in an `Optional` to let the client know that the value could be null and then they could take appropriate action.

Comment: @kfxoy50h.ajq I am afraid either you need to put null checks all over or make a cleaner and self documented API using `Optional`.

Comment: @kfxoy50h.ajq can you please accept my answer if u like it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a warning because java does not "understand" that the implementation of

```
Assert.isTrue(amazonS3 != null, "amazonS3 is null");
```

is checking for null - basically why should it? Inside `isTrue` method can be anything no matter what name this method has

you can add to the method

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
```

but basically it's better to check for nulls inside `createS3Something` and not by using `Assert` since this mechanism is rather for Tests

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to have happen when `amazonS3` is `null`?

Most practices would say to let the `null` get returned and have consuming methods check for it and decide what they want to do about it.

You should want any code that consumes your code to know when something has gone wrong. That is why exceptions exist and so many libraries throw them at the top level.